# Base64 encoding caching

Tags: css, image, caching, base64, httprequest

I am trying to decide whether to use the Base64 encoding for some images (graphics) and thumbs on one of my websites but I was not exactly able to find answer to some efficiency questions that sprouted while trying to decide.

This is my theory but I do not have enough knowledge on this area to be completely sure which is what I need help with:

> *The use of embedded base64 images reduce the number of HTTP requests, increasing the size of the file by relatively a 30%, which is ok for small images/graphics, but these images are not cached, however if you embed these base64 images into your CSS file they will be cached but as one file (the CSS).*

I need to know if I am wrong, if so how wrong or if I am missing anything important here.

**[Edit]**

I found some very useful information changing my keywords in google for [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 0):

If you have many small images that always get loaded together, you should have a look at sprites. Using sprites you get the overhead of one request but loose the overhead of base64 coding (33% more traffic). So if your sprite is 3 times bigger than your response header this saves bandwidth.

If you have many small images on a random basis use base64 coding.

Comment: Can you sprite base64 images? (this is what I am also trying to achive)

Comment: You are right, the "spriting" effect occurs inside of the CSS where we call these images as we are pretty much consolidating all of the images inside a single file plus the CSS that called them.